# How do I remove the brackets around my output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, stdout

I am trying to code a bot using discord.js, but I have little experience with JavaScript. I've setup a command that sends an image whenever the user runs it. However, the output from stdout prints this:

```
{ url: http://example.com/ }
```

How do I remove the brackets and keep the URL without breaking anything?

Here is my code:

```
run(message) {
    exec("node ~/db/imgdo.js", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            message.say(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            message.say(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }

        message.say(`${stdout}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: It's returning a JavaScript object. You probably want `JSON.parse(stdout)`. See: [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: You could return a string?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad question, I managed to figure it out myself.
After a few hours of expirementing, I figured out I can use `str.replace` to replace the unwanted characters

```
var res = str.replace(/{ url: '|' }/g, "");
```